# How to pass the edit text value to adapter class

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to pass the text value from below activity to TextAdapter class.
public class SecondActivity extends Activity  {

```
EditText et1;
TextView t1,t2;
Button b1,b2;
String result;
Context context = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_sec);
et1 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
t1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
t2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
b1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
b2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
t2.setText(et1.getText());
}
});
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),ThirdActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This values are to be added in the array
public class TextAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

```
    private String[] textViewer = new String[]{
"Hai"--------------(Here i want the edit text value)
};
public TextAdapter (Context context){
this.context= context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return textViewer.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
return view==((TextView)object);
}
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText(textViewer[position]);
((ViewPager) container).addView(textView, 0);
return textView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
((ViewPager) container).removeView((TextView) object);
}
```

}

Comment: Also note always make your question presentable so that community people provide you with good answers. You may tell you tried this thing but failed in this thing supporting it with your code. Putting direct questions will negate your points and people will hesitate you to provide with good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the context in the activity and pass the Context in the PageAdapter class like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public EditText editText = null;
private Context context = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.xxxx);

 context = this;

 AnotherClass anotherClassObject = new AnotherClass(context)
}
```

Where your page adapter class will be somewhat like this:

```
public class AnotherClass extends PageAdapter {
public AnotherClass(Context context) 
    {
       context.editText.getText().toString().trim();  // Here you will get the edittext value
    }
}
```

It may ask you to type cast the context, in that case type cast it with Activity class name.

**UPDATED:-**

Make the editText public and call

```
((SecondActivity)context).et1.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: How can I pass an instance for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620006/edittext-is-returning-null-when-accessed-from-an-adapter