# EditText is returning null when accessed from an adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, layout-inflater

I have an adapter class which uses the `getFilter` function within a `ListView`. I wanted to modify it so that when the search is empty, the EditText text color becomes red. I have the following code which doesn't FC my app but the return string is blank instead of what is in the `EditText`

My partial adapter class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            data = (ArrayList<SetRows>)results.values;
            if (data.isEmpty()) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
                EditText myTextView = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
                myTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), myTextView.getText().toString(), 2000).show();
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for(int i = 0, l = data.size(); i < l; i++)
                add(data.get(i));
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
```

How do I modify the code so that I can achieve the result?

Comment: How do you know that EditText is not blank?

Comment: As i enter character into the EditText, it searches within the ListView. When it doesn't find anything (`data.isEmpty()`) it's supposed to make the textstring RED.

Comment: And what is problem you are facing? Sorry but im little confused from question, you are getting NullPointer? or something else?

Comment: I am using `Toast` to see if the `EditText` is actually being retrieved within the adapter but it seems like it's not. I don't get a `NPE` so I am guessing it's retrieving it but not sure why the value is empty even though there is something in the `EditText`

Comment: Add here layout_main resource.

Comment: Add here your XML layout - source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity
{
    private EditText editText = null;
    // etc.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
        // etc.
    }

    private Filter listFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
        {
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
        {
            ArrayList<SetRows> data = (ArrayList<SetRows>) results.values;
            if (data.isEmpty()) YourActivity.this.editText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), myTextView.getText().toString(), 2000).show();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I can't use `YourActivity.this` because the adapter is not nested within the `Activity` itself. I get the following error: `No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope`

Comment: Where do you instanciate your adapter ?

Comment: In the MainActivity `private SetRowsCustomAdapter adapter;`

Comment: What I'd do whould be to pass the EditText instance to the Adapter with a settor. Something like `public void attachEditText(EditText editText) {}`.

Comment: I will just display a Toast which is working for now. Just wanted to avoid the Toast which kinda gets annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Try `... myTextView.getEditable().toString()`, sometimes it works

Comment: Even before the code gets to the `Toast`, I can tell nothing is happening because the `Color.RED` is not working.

Comment: Red color is to notify an error? why not use "myTextView.setError(...)"?

Comment: The `EditText` is not even being instantiated within my adapter at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the code involving `LayoutInflater` is doing what you think it is doing.

`inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null)` will not get you an existing instance of `R.layout.main`; rather it uses the XML layout defined in main.xml to generate an *entirely new View tree*.

Assuming your main Activity is calling `setContentView(R.layout.main)`, calling `inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null)` will result in you have two completely separate instances of that layout in memory. A reference to an EditText in one of these trees will be in no way related to the reference in the other tree.

Once you have inflated the second View tree, you don't seem to do anything with it, so it is never displayed to the user. The user is still interacting with the layout you created in your Activity, while you are trying to get data from this second invisible tree.

> How do I modify the code so that I can achieve the result?

There are a number of ways to do this, but without knowing how `publishResults()` is related to your Activity, it is difficult to recommend one. Here are some ideas:

- Create a callback in your Activity that performs the desired operation
- Pass a reference to your EditText to whatever class has the `publishResults()` method

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: The purpose of baseAdapters is to set data on your listview. So the checking must be done on the class where the EditText has been declared.

By utilizing the TextWatcher interface which checks the updated value of your EditText,

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher{
    private EditText searchField;
    private SearchActivity activity;
    private ListView listView;
    private String [] matches; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);

        activity = this;
        searchField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchField);
        searchField.addTextChangedListener(this);           


        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {

               //your action
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable searchField) {
        listView.setAdapter(null);

        //check for matches here and store it to newly created array of Strings

        if(searchField.length()>0 && matches.length > 0){   //added another condition here
            listView.setAdapter(new YourAdapter());         
        }else{
            this.searchField.setTextColor(Color.RED); // <--changes HERE
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I want the text to turn Red only if the search query doesn't match, not if it's less than 0, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried `if (adapter.isEmpty())` but it seems the search query has to be wrong by two letter instead of 1 for the edittext to change color.

Comment: I thought its the background color you wanted to set. Well in that case, you might want to change the textColor to red instead?

Comment: I am not changing the background color or the text color based on the length of the edittext but rather the search query matching strings within the listview. That's where I am having an issue. I WAS able to solve it in a different way but for some reason it only works if the search query has more than one character not matching the listview.