# Android - How do you pass textview values from Activity-A to an adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-adapter

I am working on a shopping cart app and I need some help on adapters. I tried to follow through a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080241/how-to-pass-the-edit-text-value-to-adapter-class) but it is a bit different from my case. I have 3 classes: `MakeSale.java`, `DetailsActivity.java` and `ShoppingCartListAdapter.java`. So, here is the flow.

In `MakeSale.java`, I have declared two array lists, the first, `cartItemArrayList` store's items to be purchased by a customer. These are producer name, product name, quantity, unitCost and the second one, `cartCostItemsList` holds the total cost of items in the shopping cart.

Inside `MakeSale.java`

```
public static List<CartItem> cartItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<Double> cartCostItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then I have an adapter class that extends `ArrayAdapter`. This class is linked to an XML, `list_item` that is displayed on a listview. Now, this `list_item` only displays the producer name, product name, total quantity, the total cost per item added to the cart. The `list_item` has been made clickable for when a user wants to make changes (increase or decrease the quantity of items to be bought)on an item on the listview.

Inside `ShoppingCartListAdapter.java`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.zynle.fisp_dealer.Dashboard;
import com.zynle.fisp_dealer.DetailsActivity;
import com.zynle.fisp_dealer.MakeSale;
import com.zynle.fisp_dealer.R;

import java.util.List;
import entities.CartItem;


public class ShoppingCartListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CartItem> {

private Context context;
private List<CartItem> cartItems;

public ShoppingCartListAdapter(Context context, List<CartItem> cartItems) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, cartItems);
    this.context = context;
    this.cartItems = cartItems;

}

public int getCount() {
    return cartItems.size();
}

public CartItem getItem(int position) {
    return cartItems.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return cartItems.get(position).getId();
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final CartItem currentProduct = getItem(position);

    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    TextView productName_txtv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    TextView producerName_txtv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.producerTextView);
    TextView productQuantity_txtv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qtyTextView);
    TextView productCost_txtv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priceTextView);

    productName_txtv.setText(cartItems.get(position).getProduct_txt());
    producerName_txtv.setText(cartItems.get(position).getProducer_txt());
    productQuantity_txtv.setText(String.valueOf(cartItems.get(position).getQuantity()));
    productCost_txtv.setText(String.valueOf(cartItems.get(position).getCost_txt()));

    productName_txtv.setText(currentProduct.getProduct_txt());

    int perItem = currentProduct.getCost_txt();
    int quantitee = currentProduct.getQuantity();

    final int total = perItem * quantitee;

    productCost_txtv.setText("Total: K" + total);
    productQuantity_txtv.setText(currentProduct.getQuantity() + " Selected");

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
            detailsIntent.putExtra("name", currentProduct.getProduct_txt());
            detailsIntent.putExtra("quantity", currentProduct.getQuantity());
            detailsIntent.putExtra("total", total);
            context.startActivity(detailsIntent);
        }
    });

    return view;
}


public void makeNewSale() {
    if (getCount() == 0) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setMessage("Cart is Empty!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Add new items", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MakeSale.class);
                        getContext().startActivity(intent);

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Dashboard.class);
                        getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

}

My code that handles all the logic on increasing and decreasing quantity on button clicks is in a class called `DetailsActivity.java`, as seen from the intent. Of course `DetailsActivity.java` is linked to some xml file.

Inside `DetailsActivity.java`

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import database.FISP_SQLiteDB;
import entities.CartItem;
import entities.Products;

public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imageView;
TextView nameTextView, priceTextView, qtyTextView, available;
Button increaseQtyButton, decreaseQtyButton, contactSupplierButton, deleteButton, confirmButton;

private List<CartItem> cartItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    // Get any data passed in from Fragment
    Intent detailsIntent = getIntent();
    final String name = detailsIntent.getStringExtra("name");

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    nameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    available = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.availableQTY);
    priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.priceTextView);
    qtyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qtyText);
    increaseQtyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increaseQtyButton);
    decreaseQtyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decreaseQtyButton);
    contactSupplierButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contactSupplierButton);
    deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteProductButton);
    confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

    nameTextView.setText(name);

    int quantityPicker = Integer.parseInt(MakeSale.quantityPicker_Npkr.getText().toString());
    qtyTextView.setText("" + quantityPicker);

    final FISP_SQLiteDB db = new FISP_SQLiteDB(DetailsActivity.this);
    final Products product = db.getProduct(name);

    if (product != null) {

        final double productPrice = (product.getPrice() * quantityPicker);
        final int subQuantity = (product.getQuantity() - quantityPicker);

        priceTextView.setText("K" + productPrice);
        available.setText("Available Quantity is " + subQuantity);

        final int[] counter = {quantityPicker};
        final int[] counter1 = {quantityPicker};
        final int[] minteger = {1};

        increaseQtyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                qtyTextView.setText(String.valueOf(counter[0]++));
                int reducingQty = (subQuantity - counter1[0]++);
                double totalingPrice = productPrice + (product.getPrice()* minteger[0]++);
                available.setText(String.valueOf("Available Quantity is " + reducingQty));
                priceTextView.setText("K" + totalingPrice);

                decreaseQtyButton.setEnabled(true);

                if(reducingQty==0){
                    increaseQtyButton.setEnabled(false);
                    decreaseQtyButton.setEnabled(true);

                }
            }
        });

        decreaseQtyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                qtyTextView.setText(String.valueOf(counter[0]--));
                int increasingQty = (subQuantity - counter1[0]--);
                double totalingPrice = productPrice - (product.getPrice()* minteger[0]--);
                available.setText(String.valueOf("Available Quantity is " + increasingQty));
                priceTextView.setText("K" + totalingPrice);

                increaseQtyButton.setEnabled(true);

                if (increasingQty==product.getQuantity()){
                    increaseQtyButton.setEnabled(true);
                    decreaseQtyButton.setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
        });

        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

                                //db.deleteProduct(name);
                                finish();
                                break;

                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };
                AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailsActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
                ab.setMessage("Delete " + name + " ?").setPositiveButton("DELETE", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", dialogClickListener).show();
            }
        });


        contactSupplierButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Creating alert Dialog with two Buttons
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailsActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
                // Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog.setTitle("Do you want to call?");
                // Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog.setMessage("" + product.getSupplierName());
                // Setting Icon to Dialog
                //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.warning);
                // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                //callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("" + product.getSupplierPhone().trim()));
                                callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + product.getSupplierPhone()));

                                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DetailsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                DetailsActivity.this.startActivity(callIntent);
                            }
                        });

                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //CartItem cartItem = new CartItem(producer, product, quantity, unitCost);
                //cartItemArrayList.add(cartItem);

                Intent intent = new Intent(DetailsActivity.this, ShoppingCart.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Now, how do I set/replace these new values (new quantity, new totalCost) into the `list_item` on the listview when the user clicks the `confirmChangesBtn`? By doing so changing the product details in the array list(`cartItemArrayList` and `cartCostItemsList`). Passing textview values from `DetailsActivity.java` to the adapter for display? How would I go about this? Anyone?

Comment: just pass the value to Adapter constructor and create a logic!

Comment: Like in DetailsActivity may be in your decrease/ increase button click listeners,  
Just access the List used in your adapter into your activity List<CartItems>

Create a method in adapter class 
public List<CartItems> getDataList() {
return cartItems ;// Your main data list at adapter.
}

Now in activity call 
List <cartItems> carttemsList = adapter.getDataList();
then  CartItems cartItems = cartItemsList.get(position); // position of view which will get affected.
cartItems.setValue("YourValue");
cartItemsList.add(cartItems, position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: You can change the by using an interface .

Comment: Where you are using `ShoppingCartListAdapter` ? show Activity Code

Comment: @phpdroid thanks, let me look into it though your response is too straight forward

Comment: @Priyavrat makes sense, let me try that too, because the items are assigned a position in the array list, so its important to maintain that even when we are editing from a different class

Comment: @Champandorid umhm your comment is not so clear, mind if you elaborate further?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK that's the challenge am having, how do I make the two files to exchange updated values and update array list

Comment: @Yokonia Tembo give it a try, it will definately help you.

Comment: @Priyavrat am trying your method now, but here is the thing. I have an increase button, decrease button and a confirmChanges button. So what did you mean by `Like in DetailsActivity may be in your decrease/ increase button click listeners, Just access the List used in your adapter into your activity List<CartItems>`

Because changes must take effect after user presses confirmChanges button

Comment: @YokoniaTembo I am writing a detailed answer for you in the same question based on my current understanding. If I miss something then let me know, I will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will also include Upendra shah's solution with my code.

Before writing the solution, I am assume that you have two activities, 1. ShoppingCart.java(Holds the listview) & DetailsActivity.java.

Please follow the steps one by one.

**Step 1.** First remove the click listener from adapter & create a new method in adapter which will return your data list. Also create a global integer variable into ShoppingCart Activity, which will hold the clicked position;

**Sub-Step 1.A** Create global variable as below in ShoppingCart Activity

```
// This will be updated when user clicks on any item of listview.
int clickedPosition = -1;
```

**Sub-Step 1.B** Creating proper listview click listener.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
            detailsIntent.putExtra("name", currentProduct.getProduct_txt());
            detailsIntent.putExtra("quantity", currentProduct.getQuantity());
            detailsIntent.putExtra("total", total);
            context.startActivity(detailsIntent);
        }
    });
```

remove this code, after that go to the ShoppingCart activity(Where your listview object exist). There write the below mentioned code.

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // updating clicked position variable on list item click.
            clickedPosition = position; 
            Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(ShopingCart.this, DetailsActivity.class);
            detailsIntent.putExtra("name", currentProduct.getProduct_txt());
            detailsIntent.putExtra("quantity", currentProduct.getQuantity());
            detailsIntent.putExtra("total", total);
            startActivityForResult(detailsIntent);
        }
    });
```

Now code for method which will return your adapter datalist.

```
public List<CartItems> getCartItemsFromAdapter() {
      return cartItems;
}
```

**Step 2.** At Shopping cart activity, override onActivityResult

```
    @Override  
           protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
           {  
               super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
               if(requestCode == 121)  
                  {  
                    // Update the values according to you, I am using sample key-value.
                    String updatedCost = data.getStringExtra("updatedCost");   
                    List<CartItems> cartItems = adapter.getCartItemsFromAdapter();
                    CartItems cartItemObj = cartItems.get(clickedPosition);
                    cartItemObj.setTotalCost(updatedCost);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Calling this method will quickly reflect your changes to listView.
                  }  
         }
```

**Step 3.** Finally at your DetailsActivity Confirm Button or any button on which click you want to reflect these changes, Write the below mentioned code.

```
confirmBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener{

Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.putExtra("updatedCost", totalCostValue);  
setResult(121, intent);
finish();

});
```

Comment: thanks so much @Priyavrat, your guess was right on `ShoppingCart.java` except am running through some errors. In Sub-Step 1.B, am getting an error on `startActivityForResult(detailsIntent);`, says `Cannot resolve method startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent)`. Tried changing my `ShoppingCart.java` class to extend `Activity` but nothing is changing.

Comment: then in Step 2, am getting an error on  `Intent data`. Says `Cannot resolve symbol 'data'`. My `onActivityResult`, `requestCode` and `resultCode` Variables are never used. Then another error on `ShoppingCartListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. The error says `Non-static method 'notifyDataSetChanged()' cannot be referenced from a static context`. Perhaps something to do with how am using the Java keyword `final` in my code?

Comment: 1. For  sub-step 1.B Make sure ShoppingCart.java is an activity and you defined itemClick listener(as mentioned in answer) for lisitview.
2. In Step 2 make sure your onActivityResult() method is in ShoppingCart.java
3. Don't treat notifyDataSetChanged() as static method. It is an pre-defined method of adapter class. Call like adapterObj.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
By using these steps, you will be done. 
Let me know
Thanks.

Comment: still negative on `startActivityForResult(detailsIntent);`. everything you told me has worked so far except for that. `ShoppingCart.java` is there and defined in the manifest. And the `itemClick` listener has been done the way you suggested it the answer above. But for some reason, my `startActivityForResult(detailsIntent);` still gives an error. Clearly, am missing something

Comment: Are you sure ShoppingCart.java(your class) , an activity ?

If it is not an activity then you need to call context.startActivityForResult() like this. Still have the problem then let me know the code or how can I help you.
Thanks.

Comment: thanks @Priyavrat. It worked. Turns out the `startActivityForResult(detailsIntent)` was expecting an intent and a request code. The intent, `detailsIntent` in my case was provided but the requsest code was not. Looked something like this `startActivityForResult(detailsIntent, 1)`

Comment: @YokoniaTembo If it is worked, then please up-vote my answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change adapter data when user change the shop cart value from details page and again show in adapter with new values , you should initialize adapter view inside on Resume method and notify the adapter view , it help you to recreate the view with new value.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(arrayList.size()>0) {
            myShoppingCartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            getAllShoppingCartDetails();
        }

    }
```

Comment: in which class should I initialize the adapter view, where do I put the Resume method?

Comment: @mayank garg this is not optimum thing to every time update/ refresh the list in onResume(); onResume may be fired in many reason, one is like, lock and unlock again phone. In that case onResume() will be fired and the list data will be updated unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

I refer your code than I suggest to use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` in adapter.

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
            detailsIntent.putExtra("name", currentProduct.getProduct_txt());
            detailsIntent.putExtra("quantity", currentProduct.getQuantity());
            detailsIntent.putExtra("total", total);
            context.startActivityForResult(detailsIntent, 121);
        }
    });
```

than when you increase and decrease quntity than add your updated data to intent and `setResult()`

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
setResult(121,intent);
finish();
```

than handle your result back in your activity

```
@Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
           // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
           if(requestCode==121)  
              {  
                String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                //Do you logic like update ui, list, price 
              }  
     }
```

Comment: which class am I calling the `onActivityResult` method?? You just said I handle result back in my activity

Comment: what you want after getting result back from DetailsActivity ??

Comment: I want to change adapter data when user changes the shop cart values from details page. Then show in listview with new values

Comment: Ok, than in `onActivityResult` update list data which have changed and than notify to adapter about data set are changed using `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()`

Answer (score 0):

@Yokonia Tembo,

In your code of `DetailsActivity.java` in side `increaseQtyButton.setOnClickListener()` I did not find changing process for `cartItemArrayList` of `MakeSales.java` class

I think Changes in those array list before `notifyDataSetChanged()` of adapter will update value in your CartList.

Apart form this there is other suggestion, 
If you are working for ShoppingCart app, you should make a database table for cart items instead of **ArrayList** you will be benefited by few things mentioned bellow

- DB table implementation will make your cart items available even after killing and restarting the app.
- You can put observers on the table columns update so that increasing/decreasing value will notify UI to update items

Comment: so you are saying I should import the `cartItemArrayList` from `MakeSales.java` into my `DetailsActivity.java` and make changes directly from my +/- buttons? If so, how then does the adapter come  in

Comment: No you don't need to import all item from `MakeSales.java` , But you need to Update correct `CartItem` object of the `cartItemArrayList` so that updated value will be available throughout the app. 

About the Adapter, If you ever make any run-time changes in dataset of adapter, it is always suggested to use notify the adapter for refreshing the view, for more details please visit https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()